# ggradar: use group plus facet_wrap at the same time in

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the ggradar package which makes very nice radar plots. I can use it to create one radar plot with multiple lines using a column called "group". Or, I can create multiple radar facets with a single line. But, I can't have facets with multiple lines (groups). Is this possible?

Note I'm using ggradar (https://github.com/ricardo-bion/ggradar) and not ggiraphExtra::ggRadar

```
library(ggradar)
library(scales)

set.seed(123)
gdat <- tibble(
  facet=c('A','A','B','B'),
  group=c(2010,2020,2010,2020),
  var1=rescale(runif(4)),
  var2=rescale(runif(4)),
  var3=rescale(runif(4)))
```

What I would like to have is two panels (A and B), each with two lines (2010, 2020). The following does not work.

```
gdat %>%
ggradar() +
  facet_wrap(vars(facet))
```

> NULL

However, if I only select one "facet" I can use group to plot 2010, 2020 on the same plot.

```
gdat %>%
  filter(facet=='A') %>%
  select(-facet) %>%
  ggradar()
```

[image: One facet two lines]

Or, I can have multiple facets, but each only has one line

```
gdat %>%
  filter(group==2010) %>%
  mutate(group=facet) %>% #need to rename "facet" to "group"
  select(-facet) %>%
  ggradar() +
    facet_wrap(vars(group))
```

[image: Two facets one line]

Is it possible to have two facets two lines?